# Show data for only a specific user in Laravel

Tags: database, laravel

I am building a Laravel website where people can post tasks into a database.  Currently, when I post tasks via my form, every account can see the data.  How can I show data for only the specific person who posted it?

- [My blade file](http://pastebin.com/GjFCbEFx)
- [My task controller file](http://pastebin.com/sG9EFhqh)

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If your user has logged in the you can retrieve their id by Auth::user()->id;

In your index() method remove `$tasks = Task::all();` and add

```
$userId = Auth::user()->id;
$tasks = Task::where('user_id',$userId)->get();
```

Hope this will help

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, however then it searches a user_id in the table of tasks, but the user_id is in the table of users. Is there a way to search the user_id in another table?  Tasks table: https://gyazo.com/52c0ec2841a89cc1876906046d094b3e Users table: https://gyazo.com/cefd9b240399d20ce534edfa8278f98f

Comment: No you should add user_id to task table which will be the foreign key of user table. Otherwise you will not be able to store the task of a particular user. It's good practice to add user_id. Relations are the important part of Rdbms. You should always design your dB in standard way. One integer column in your dB won't take much space

Comment: Thank you, that works! Only when i create now a task it doesnt automatically assign the user_id to a user i have to manually set the user_id to a user in the database?